# Cloudfront Log Headers

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-athena

My Cloudfront distribution logs to S3, and I query these logs with Athena - fairly standard.

I have a particular set of requests coming in from a partner company which sets a header. I need to be able to exclude these requests from my queries in Athena.

Cloudfront doesn't log the headers so I attempted to use Cloudfront functions (viewer request) to add the header value as a query string parameter. The problem with this is it appears that Cloudfront logs the request *before* the viewer request Lambda is run so my URI modification never makes it to the logs.

I'm looking for a way to identify requests made by a particular source which identifies itself using a header.